# Javascript/JQuery Local File System

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I have a problem regarding creating an XML file via a web browser and being able to read/write from it.
Multiple browsers have issues with this and I cant seem to find a solution that works.

I am creating a CMS which displays XML data in  fields. I then want to read the values of those input elements and then overwrite the XML file using Javascript or JQuery.

The XML file will be stored on a web server and the client PC's will access the CMS via a webpage on the server and then reading/writing to the XML.

The Code below gives you an idea of what IM trying to do:

```
 var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var FILENAME ="xml.xml"; //<---- In Current Directory on Web server. 

        var file = fso.CreateTextFile(FILENAME, true);
        file.WriteLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n');
        file.WriteLine('<Seating_Plan>\n');


        var table = document.getElementById("table_assoc");
        var rCount = table.rows.length;

        for (var i = 1; i < rCount; i++) {

            var id = table.rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value;
            var deptcode = table.rows[i].cells[1].children[0].value;
            var name = table.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].value;
            var role = table.rows[i].cells[3].children[0].value;
            var desc = table.rows[i].cells[4].children[0].value;
            var image = table.rows[i].cells[5].children[0].value;
            var asdir = table.rows[i].cells[6].children[0].value;

            file.WriteLine('<Person id="' + id + '"><Dept>' + deptcode + '</Dept><Name>' + name + '</Name><Description>' + desc + '</Description><Role>' + role + '</Role><Image><image href="' + image + '"/></Image><AssociateDir><AssociateDir href="' + asdir + '"/></AssociateDir></Person>');
        }

        file.WriteLine('</Seating_Plan>');
        file.Close();
    }
```

**However,** This works only when accessing the webpage on a local system rather than the Server eg. via: "file://C:..." rather than:

```
http://localhost/admin.html
```

What is the best way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.
Many thanks!
Aj

Comment: I don't think that JS is the good language to create/manipulate files.

You can create an array, json it to a php script and create the file on the server side.

Comment: Well that code is IE only since they are the only ones that support ActiveX. Secondly if you want to write to the server, you will need  to use a serverside language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're misunderstanding something here:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var FILENAME ="xml.xml"; //<---- In Current Directory on Web server.
```

The web browser can't access the *server's* file system.  That ActiveX object may allow file system access on the *current host*, but it's not going to allow it on *other hosts*.  If there are no errors and the browser is allowing the ActiveX object to interact with the local file system then I'll bet it's successfully creating the file *on the local file system*.  (In whatever happens to be the current working directory for the browser process, since no directory was specified.)

To interact with files *on the server's file system* you'll need to use server-side code.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, basically the whole website and xml is stored on the server, and I am simply trying to allow access to read and write through the browser; via any client pc. Browsers dont seem to like cross domain checking or whatever its called. AJAX wont work on a client PC trying to access the servers XML file, it will only work if using the http://localhost/ url. Also if I do access the local host url the ActiveX object in the browser doesn't work (to write to the XML file on the server) via the client PC. IF that makes sense. How do i get around that?